# Implementing a directed graph in python

Tags: python

I read [Python Patterns - Implementing Graphs](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/). However this implementation is inefficient for getting the edges that point to a node.

In other languages a common solution is using a two-dimensional array, but to do this in Python would require a list of lists. This does not seem pythonic.

What is an implementation of a directed graph in python where finding all the nodes with edges to and from a node (as two separate lists) is fast?

Comment: Why is a list of lists not Pythonic? 2D lists are quite commonly used in Python. You can also use the well-developed [numpy.ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), which implements n-dimensional arrays and supports indexing by row or by column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scipy offers efficient Graph routines if computational efficiency or scientific computing is your concern:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html

Comment: And compressed sparse matrices are even better than normal 2D arrays for representing graphs, I believe. More efficient in terms of space.

Comment: what if I don't know the number of nodes in graph? How do I remove/add nodes on the go efficiently using matrices?

Answer (score 7):

Another library you could use is [NetworkX](http://networkx.org/).
It provides a implementation of [directed graphs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html) that provide functions to get incomming edges `DiGraph.in_edges()` and outgoing edges `DiGraph.out_edges()` for arbitrary sets of nodes.
Usage samples are provided in the linked documentation, but unfortunately I didn't see any details about efficiency or run time.

Answer (score 7):

[networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx) is definitely the most popular Python graph library.  It is well documented, has a great API, and is performant.  Suppose you have the following graph:

[image]

Here's how to create this graph and calculate all the edges that are pointing to node e:

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from([("root", "a"), ("a", "b"), ("a", "e"), ("b", "c"), ("b", "d"), ("d", "e")])
print(graph.in_edges("e")) # => [('a', 'e'), ('d', 'e')]
```

Here's how you can calculate all the edges that node b points towards:

```py
print(graph.out_edges("b")) # => [('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

networkx is a fantastic library.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/python/dag-directed-acyclic-graph-networkx/) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer your graph question, but you can certainly implement a 2D list in Python without resorting to lists of lists in at least two ways:

You can simply use a dictionary:

```
import collections
t = collections.defaultdict(int)

t[0, 5] = 9
print t[0, 5]
```

This also has the advantage that it is sparse.

For a fancier approach, but one requiring more work, you can use a 1d list and compute the index using the 2D coordinates along with the table's height and width.

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self._table = [None,] * (width * height)
        self._width = width

    def __getitem__(self, coordinate):
        if coordinate[0] >= width or coordinate[1] >= height:
            raise IndexError('Index exceeded table dimensions')
        if coordinate[0] < 0 or coordinate[1] < 0:
            raise IndexError('Index must be non-negative')
        return self._table[coordinate[1] * width + coordinate[0]]

    def __setitem__(self, coordinate, value):
        if coordinate[0] >= width or coordinate[1] >= height:
            raise IndexError('Index exceeded table dimensions')
        if coordinate[0] < 0 or coordinate[1] < 0:
            raise IndexError('Index must be non-negative')
        self._table[coordinate[1] * width + coordinate[0]] = value


t = Table(10,10)
t[0, 5] = 9
print t[0, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Pygraph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/). I've used it quite a bit for large directed (and undirected) graphs without memory or run-time issues, though it is all implemented in Python so a C++ wrapped implementation could be much fast.