# Good way to represent a data form in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted some general advice on how to represent a certain data form in image format. I have two arrays `A` and `B`.

`A[0]=array([0, 1]), A[1]=array([0, 3])` represents connection from 0 to 1 and 0 to 3 respectively. In general, `[i,j]` elements in `A` represent connection from `i` to `j`.

`B[0]=array([1]), B[1]=array([2])` represents the corresponding values for connections from 0 to 1 and 0 to 3 respectively.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[0, 1],
            [0, 3],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 4],
            [2, 5],
            [3, 4],
            [4, 5]])

B=np.array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7]])
```

The expected output is

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is to set up a directed graph with labeled edges. For that, I believe networkx (https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) should have what you need. See also [Implementing a directed graph in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869644/implementing-a-directed-graph-in-python).